# Is it possible to add non model field to method body in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to add non model field for instance to PATCH body? Let's take as an example that I would like to change password of the user. In my model I have only field `password` however in PATCH I would like to add `old_password` to authenticate user and then update password from `password` field from body. Any ideas? I found `SerializerMethodField` but I am not sure whether it is possible to do what I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add your fields to your serializer

```
class MyPatchSerializer(...):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(...)
    fields = [..., 'old_password']
```

if you want to validate this field simply add add a `validate_old_pasword(self, value)` to your serializer, [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

then in your viewset class you need to override `get_serializer_class` ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself)), this way you tell DRF that if user is sending a PUT/PATCH request instead of default serializer you should use `MyPatchSerializer`

```
class MyViewSet(...):
    ...

    def get_serializer(self):
        if self.action in ('update', 'partial_update'):
            return MyPatchSerializer
        return self.serializer_class
```

Comment: Also remember to add the field as read_only, because if you use this serializer to serialize the model instead of converting raw data to internal value it will raise an exception.